# Cypress - TypeError: cannot read property 'KeyboardEvent' of undefined (Cypress version - 5.5.0)

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

While executing the code it is throwing TypeError for - cy.get('css').type('pqr.com').

''' at Keyboard.fireSimulatedEvent ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162534:29)     at Keyboard.simulatedKeydown ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162679:59)     at Keyboard.typeSimulatedKey ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162719:11)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162396:15) From previous event:     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162405:66) From previous event:     at Keyboard.type ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162404:61)     at type ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:153804:24)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:153999:21) From previous event:     at onReady ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:153975:15)     at runAllChecks ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150154:15)     at retryActionability ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150163:17) From previous event:     at tryFn ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:165407:22)     at whenStable ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:165445:13)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:164960:17) From previous event:     at $Cy.retry ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:164940:39)     at retryActionability ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150166:20)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150168:8) From previous event:     at Object.verify ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150095:22)     at handleFocused ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:153947:30)     at Context.type ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:154006:13)     at Context. ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169891:22)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169315:16) From previous event:     at runCommand ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169294:9)     at next ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169440:15)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169468:17) From previous event:     at next ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169440:35) From previous event:     at Promise.catch.err.name ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169481:38) From previous event:     at run ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169474:22)     at $Cy.cy. [as get] ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169931:12)     at Context.runnable.fn ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:170155:22)     at callFn ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104227:22)     at Test.../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js.Runnable.run ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104214:8)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175754:29) From previous event:     at Object.onRunnableRun ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175742:18)     at $Cypress.action ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:166291:29)     at Test.Runnable.run ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:174128:14)     at Runner.../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js.Runner.runTest ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104886:11)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105012:13)     at next ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104795:15)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104805:8)     at next ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104707:15)     at  ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104773:6)     at timeslice ({{URL}}/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:98699:28) '''

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code sample?

Comment: Due to security reason I can not provide the exact code snippet. However I can explain it; web application which I am trying to automate contains the different text boxes. I have experienced that this issue is not related to the specific filed. But it is something relevant to the previous filed.
Using Cypress (cy.get('selector').type('text')) I am able to type the proper value into one field and then when I try to enter the text into another text, mentioned issue is occurred. I have checked with changing the order of the text box and found that it is not specific to the particular field.

Comment: Also to note that, it is not throwing error if I try cy.get('selector').clear().

Comment: I had a similar issue and Needed to clear the cypress catche and reinstall Cypress like in this post https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5440#issuecomment-547851042

Comment: Yes @RosenMihaylov, I did reinstall it and it started working for me properly.